# Open Source Webmaps and Geotiffs

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, web-mapping, geotiff-tiff, geodesy

I have recently started to learn how to use open source web maps, and have come across the following issue.

When using geoserver and geo explorer (part of the open-geo-suite), I seem to get an annoying white box around my geotiff (see pic) almost like its been re projected or something. The geodetics of the geotiff are WGS UTM30. Ive tried re projecting the image to different projections but im having zero luck..

[image]

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: what projection is your map in? what does the GeoTiff look like in the layer preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might probably need to convert your geodetics from WGS UTM30 into web mercator auxiliary sphere (EPG 900913). That should do the trick!